How to filter Pandas Dataframe to integer values?
I have a dataframe column with string values. I want to filter to the rows that have integer. I can do the below to find if it's numeric, but this would return floats as well.
result = pd.to_numeric(df['col1'], errors='coerce').notnull()

'1' should be returned
'1.1' should not be returned.
How do I filter to integers (excluding floats)?

Since the column dtype is string, you can filter using str.contains -> df['r'].str.contains(r'.')

What if you have 1.0?

You could use regex to match for strings that are integers but not floats.
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["a", "b", "c", "2000.12121", 
                        "99900000", "1", "1.1", "2", "abc"]})
# Regex to match integers
is_integer_regex = "(?<![\d.])[0-9]+(?![\d.])"
filtered_col1 = df[df.col1.str.match(is_integer_regex)]

print(filtered_col1)
>>>       col1  
    4    99900000    
    5    1  
    7    2 


You can check whether the numeric value floors to itself:
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["1", "1.1", "2", "abc"]})
s = pd.to_numeric(df["col1"], errors="coerce")
s == np.floor(s)


Same concept, but slightly different, would be checking values against mod 1  i.e. s.mod(1) == 0 though I don't know which operation would be faster at scale that way is chainable at least pd.to_numeric(df["col1"], errors="coerce").mod(1).eq(0).

Another possible solution, which is based on pandas.Series.str.isnumeric:
df['result'] = df['col1'].str.isnumeric()

Output:
  col1  result
0    1    True
1  1.1   False
2    2    True
3  abc   False


Worth mentioning that this will also return false on any negative value. So -9 would be excluded even though it is an integer.

Thanks, @HenryEcker, for commenting my solution. That is true, but it is also unclear whether the OP has only positive integers.

You can remove the strings that contain a period with str.replace:
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['1', '1.0', '1.01', '1.1', 'one']})

df['result'] = pd.to_numeric(
    df['col1'].str.replace(r'.*\.0?[1-9]+.*', '', regex=True), errors='coerce'
).notnull()

Or with str.contains and mask:
df['result'] = pd.to_numeric(
    df['col1'].mask(df['col1'].str.contains(r'\.0?[1-9]+')), errors='coerce'
).notnull()

Or, removing the potential trailing '.0', map and str.isdigit:
df['result'] = df['col1'].str.rstrip('.0').map(str.isdigit)

Output:
   col1  result
0     1    True
1   1.0    True
2  1.01   False
3   1.1   False
4   one   False

Note that if you want to consider 1.0 invalid, you can adapt the above to:
df['result'] = pd.to_numeric(
    df['col1'].mask(df['col1'].str.contains(r'\.')), errors='coerce'
).notnull()

#    col1  result
# 0     1    True
# 1   1.0   False  # now considered invalid
# 2  1.01   False
# 3   1.1   False
# 4   one   False

